# server.port properties not working after buildin spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

i'm working on spring boot project and all works fine , now i want to build and run the app.
in the application.properties file i set the property `server.port = 8090`
after building the project using maven i run the following command 
`java -jar jarfilename.jar` but it says the port `8080` is already in use.
i try these commands:

```
java -jar  -Dport=8090 jarfilename.jar
```

and

```
java -jar  jarfilename.jar --port=8090
```

but also i got the same message  the port `8080` is already in use.

I'm wondering why it takes the  port number `8080`  and ignore the port number `8090` that i set in the application.properties file.

Note : (I'm using tomcat embedded server) and  when i check the folder target/classes.. application.properties i didn't find the property `server.port=8090`.

can anyone explain to me what' happen exacly?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the: "java -jar  -Dserver.port=8090 jarfilename.jar" command

Comment: Hi @SándorJuhos thank you so much , it works fine , but can you explain me please why it ignores the property server.port = 8090 in the application.properties file ?

Comment: @Ali, are you using springboot with embedded tomcat or a standalone tomcat? `server.port` only works in embedded tomcat mode. If you are using a standalone tomcat, then it doesn't work. You have to set the port by manually configuring in `server.xml` of tomcat. Can you confirm?

Comment: thank you @harshavmb for your timr, yes i'm using embedded tomcat , but i solved the probelm, regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the application.properties located at the right location?
Description from [Spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties files in the following locations and add them to the Spring Environment:
>
> 1. A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
> 2. The current directory
> 3. A classpath /config package
> 4. The classpath root
>
> The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations higher in the list override those defined in lower locations).

Use `java -jar -Dserver.port=8090 jarfilename.jar` to set the port from command line.

Hint, from [Spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html): If you want to use the short term `-Dport=8090`, you can use `server.port=${port:8080}` in your application property file.

Comment: I get this error: 
`'-jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem, in my case, I didn't pass the args to SpringApplication.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MySpringConfiguration.class);
}
```

should be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MySpringConfiguration.class, args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The application.properties file is excluded.

---

Go to project properties -> Java Build Path -> <Choose your project's /src/main/resources> -> Double click on Excluded -> Remove (** pattern mostly) -> Apply.

---

Now recheck

Answer (score 0):

when you create spring boot application using 'spring initializer' select jar file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I configured SERVER_PORT environment variable and had same problem. With this variable configured, the application.properties does not work. After remove environment variable "SERVER_PORT" or just edit it, I could change the port.

Reference: [Spring - 78.3 Change the HTTP Port](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html)

Answer (score -1):

I know its an old post, but I might know the answer(maybe it will help others): **There is a hierarchy with the configuration settings.**

The *applicaton.properties file is at the bottom*(OS env. variables, Java System properties etc. are all above), on the other hand, *terminal parameters are at the top*.

So  when the server initialized, it used the port from a property setting, that is higher in the hierarchy ladder.

Comment: FIY: in PowerShell the "-Dserver.port= " parameter doesnt work, you can use the "--server.port=" instead, but it should be after the path of the jar file. With CMD, both works.